# ExoPlayer stops playing in background

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have an application that keeps a global instance of an ExoPlayer instance to facilitate audio streams in the background.
After opening lots of apps, the audio stops playing.

It happens as follows:

- open `Activity` that starts playing audio
- press back button to close `Activity`
- the audio is still playing and keeps doing so if you leave the device alone (as intended)

However, when you open a dozen or more apps after the last step, the ExoPlayer stops playing at some point.
My guess is that a memory cleanup happens and thus ExoPlayer gets deallocated. I tried to get more information from the logs, but that has provided little help so far.

Keeping a reference of the ExoPlayer inside an `android.app.Service` doesn't make a difference.

The device I am testing on is a Nexus 5 with Android 5.1.x, but the issue happens on other devices too.

I couldn't find a solution in the ExoPlayer [documentation](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html) pages nor on StackOverflow or Google. Does anyone know the correct way to prevent the ExoPlayer from stopping playback?

Comment: Have you tried putting it on a foreground `Service`?

Comment: Yep, I tried keeping a reference of it in an `android.app.Service`.

Comment: I wonder if it would make a difference if it gets created from within that Service though...

Comment: I don't mean just any service, but one started in the [foreground](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!

Comment: @Ricardo It worked. If you add your answer, I'll accept it. I also found a confirmation of that solution in the ExoPlayer bug tracker: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/421

Comment: Cool, just did. Glad it worked.

Comment: I am also working for the same, So in that case I need to create ExoPlayer instance in foreground service?

Comment: Yes: If you want audio playing in the background, you need to keep a reference to an ExoPlayer instance in a foreground service.

Comment: what am i missing? am i supposed to start a `Service` that inside of it i start the activity that holds the `ExoPlayer`? what if i want to start the activity with `startActivityForResult`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make sure a `Service` stays alive as much as possible without being killed by the system, you need to make sure you start it as a [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground).

This means there will be a notification informing the user of the active service so he can be aware of it. Because of that, you must start the service with a corresponding notification. Here is the example from the docs:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),
            System.currentTimeMillis()); 
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class); 
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0); 
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
            getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent); 
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this knowledge! +1

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal Is this code block working on your end ?

Comment: for future visitors: Android 8.0+ requires Channel id for notifications. More information here. https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Comment: Would it be possible to update this answer for recent updates of Android ? Thanks!