# ExoPlayer EventListener not be called in background

Tags: android, audio-player, exoplayer, android-music-player

In my `PlaybackService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat`I implement EventListener like this:

```
exoPlayer.addListener(new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {
@Override
public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
}

@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int state) {
}
```

When app in foreground, it's OK but when app in background, I don't know how to catch ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED

Give me some advice, thank you!

Comment: Is player state changing in background?

Comment: Check this Solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400026/exoplayer-stops-playing-in-background?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @AjayVenugopal thank you, but it's not my problem. My service isn't be killed. I just want to catch then STATE_ENDED event

Comment: @Nizam yes, in background, my service is ok