# How can i keep my `ExoPlayer` running while my app is in the background?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have an activity that holds 2 instances of an `ExoPlayer` because I needed to create a queue that buffers the next video and I don't know which video is coming after the next one. I need those two players to also keep playing when my app is in the background. how can I achieve it? I tried `Foreground Service` but I saw that I need to click on the notification in order to continue to my activity. I need to go into the desired activity immediately.

Comment: Please have a look at this question, maybe you will get some idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400026/exoplayer-stops-playing-in-background

Comment: @VicJordan i was following this post. the notification shoots, but i need to click it in order to shoot the `PendingIntent`. i want this step to be invisible to my users and i still need to achieve background playback for the `ExoPlayer`s.

Comment: `Foreground Service` is what you need. You can achieve your required behavior if you design the service correctly.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko can you elaborate a bit more please? if I'm getting you right i'm understanding that in the current situation i have activity `A` and i want to start from it activity `B` which holds the players. so now i start a `Service` from activity `A` that on the service's `onStartCommand` i start activity `B` with `startForeground`, a `Notification` and an `Intent` for the desired activity `B`. am i supposed to start from `A` directly `B` and then start a service that hold only the players? how can i still control them inside activity `B`? thank you